# Different output using difference method of iteration over a vector C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I want to iterate over a vector in C++11. I used two different approach for creating a loop. The first one is using auto and the other one is getting elements by index. It is really strange for me and it would be great if someone explains to me that why the output of these two are different.

```
for (auto tbl = schema.begin();tbl != schema.end(); tbl++)
{
    cout << "tbl: " << tbl->getTblName() << tbl->getAry()<<endl;
    vector<Column> clm = tbl->getColumns();
    for (int i = 0; i < clm.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << "clm1:" << clm.at(i).getAttrName() << endl;

    }
    for (auto cl = tbl->getColumns().begin(); cl != tbl->getColumns().end(); cl++)
        cout << "clm2:" << cl->getAttrName() << endl;

}
```

The output is:

```
tbl: users4
**clm1:uid**
clm1:age
clm1:sex
clm1:occupation
**clm2:P�M**  // this is the problem. It only prints random char.
clm2:age
clm2:sex
clm2:occupation
```

Comment: Need to see your `getColumns()` function. Does it return a copy or a reference?

Comment: `auto cl = tbl->getColumns().begin();` have you watched The Walking Dead?

Comment: @Ninja it returns a copy of vector. The vector definition is: `vector <Column>` . C

Comment: @Juan what?????

Comment: Then you have your answer below.  Don't return a copy, or if you do, you need to cache the copy until you're done with it. Even in the case that the iterators were still valid they would not point to the same container, leading to more errors.

Comment: Sorry for the bad joke. `cl` is dead, and you are trying to use it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getColumns()` is declared as return-by-value, then for `auto cl = tbl->getColumns().begin();`, `tbl->getColumns()` will return a brand-new copied `vector`, which is a temporary and will be destroyed after the expression immediately; so `cl` is always a dangled iterator, deference on it causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Another issue is that for `cl != tbl->getColumns().end();`, `tbl->getColumns()` will return another copied `vector`, which is a temporary too. That means you're trying to compare two iterators which belong to different containers. That's UB too.

On the ohter hand, in the 1st code sample you're using a named variable `clm` which represents the only one `vector`, which won't cause above troubles.

Comment: `getColumns()` return  a copy of vector `vector<Column>`.  I still don't get it what cause the problem. because for other member of `Table` I have the same problem. I have 3 tables and for all of these three table, I get the same output.

Comment: The problem is it is undefined behavior. Every time you make a copy of the vector it is a new container. The begin iterator points to one copy, the end points to another copy (or copies if the compiler chooses to call the function on every loop iteration), neither are related or comparable to each other even when they are valid. It may appear to mostly work, but that's the trouble with undefined behavior. If you wish to use that pattern you must return a reference to the vector.